# Creating a cluster server in WAS

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I created before a cluster server that contains different nodes and deployed an application then accessed it on the `port number 9080`

How can i create a cluster with different nodes of AppSrv and access application on the same port 
Can any one discuss me in this point?

Comment: please reword "but as a load balancing i tried to turn off on of the appSrv then access on the same port it doesn't.. "

Comment: sorry still impossible to parse out a question

Comment: Updated.. Still impossible! @covener

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but I do have an answer for you. If you delete the old clusters/servers on the node you will not get the default ports (ie/9080) when making a new cluster/server on the same node. It actually remembers the most recently used ports and uses that +1 (so 9081) regardless if 9080 is available. My understanding is that you want the default ports to be used (so 9080). In that case you would need to ensure that the "generate unique ports"  option/flag is not selected when creating the new cluster/servers. This link here may help you https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRMWJ_6.0.0.21/com.ibm.isim.doc/installing/tsk/tsk_ic_ins_was_85_cluster.htm

Answer (score 0):

addNode command best practices below should help you to create the cluster with different nodes.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_nodetips.html

For information about port numbers, see the Port number settings topic.

Answer (score 0):

To be frank with you, you can't create another cluster to access the same port, because it's already in use. If you dont precise the port it will get the default 9081, but if you force it to redirect the application to 9080, then none are going to work, u'll get a socket error.

Your solution : One of the clusters should access the 9080 port